# how to change the animation for ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-include

I have a div with ng-include to display content from external files.

```
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;" ng-class="animClass"
     ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
```

To assign different animation for content changes I am using ng-class with the assigned var animClass. Before assigning a new templateUrl a new animClass is assigned in the click handler:

```
    var currNr;
    $scope.onClick = function (nr) {
    if (nr < currNr) {
        $scope.animClass = 'moveRight';
    } else {
        $scope.animClass = 'moveLeft';
    }
    currNr = nr;
    $scope.templateUrl = 'page' + nr + '.html';
    }
```

To animate the content change I am using the following JavaScript:

```
app.animation('.moveLeft', function () {
return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            left: '100%'
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 1500, done);
    },
    leave: function (element, done) {
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            left: '0%'
        }).animate({
            left: '-100%'
        }, 1500, done);
    }
}
});

app.animation('.moveRight', function () {
return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            left: '-100%'
        }).animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, 1500, done);
    },
    leave: function (element, done) {
        element.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            left: '0%'
        }).animate({
            left: '100%'
        }, 1500, done);
    }
}
});
```

I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G8qrWCWe0FOES4fIcYav?p=preview) and it works almost fine. By clicking from page 1 to page4 the animation 'moveLeft' is used and from page 4 to 1 the animation 'moveRight' is used. 
However, by changing the direction a mix of both animations is used. 
I have no Idea how to fix this.